# Algorithm to compute shortest knight distance (chess)

Tags: java, distance, chess, shortest

I'm trying to implement the absolute rank-file distance described on [*Knight-Distance*](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Knight-Distance) from the [*Chess Programming Wiki*](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/), but I'm a little confused on what `int`s `a` and `b` are supposed to be in

```
int knightDistance(int a, int b).
```

Don't you need two sets of coordinates to figure this out (start location and destination)?
I thought maybe they were using 0,0 as the start and then you just give the difference between start and end locations, but that gives bad output.

How is this supposed to work, and does this algorithm work for any size grid, or just 8×8?

Comment: `int knightDistance(int a, int b)` appears several times on this site, which one are you referring to? The Knight Fill has a very different approach, the b1, and b2 represent a set encoded in a 64 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `a` and `b` are the rank and file distance deltas from the current position. From symmetry, only the difference between the current position and the desired destination matter.

Comment: This is correct. This was also my first instinct, I just forgot to put use the absolute value of the difference between destX-startX and destY-startY. It works as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: Another question: does this algorithm work for any size grid, or just 8x8?

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: It makes me wait 10 minutes before accepting an answer.

Comment: @user2503227 Oops, I didn't check the time (or I forgot about the time limit).  I see that you've accepted answers in the past, too.  I'll remove my first comment. But still, happy square hopping.

Comment: @user2503227 - Because the various implementations use look-up tables of limited size, that code will only work for grids that do not exceed 8x8.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: So I don't really understand a lot of what's going on in this code. How would I go about making it support 9x9 grids?

Comment: @user2503227 - The table sizes would have to change, of course. Based on what's suggested by the page, you can initialize the tables by using a [knight-fill algorithm](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Knight+Pattern#KnightFill) on a 9x9 board. You'll have to work out the logic of how the 8x8 representations work to come up with your own 9x9 versions.